# A question regarding Grothendieck , topos and (adelic??) points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, math-history

I am having a look at [this conference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNgvvNx_P9w) by Bertrand Toen about Grothendieck's work.

At 1:14:30 and after, Toen presents the new objects emerging from topos theory in algebraic geometry. He takes the following example: one wants to solve the algebraic equation $$X = 0$$ 
He says that in a classical framework, it just gives us the solution $0$, so it's a point. Not that interesting. But with the topos point of view, it gives different solutions depending on *where* we solve the equation: over $\mathbb C$ it gives a point (as before), but over a finite field $\mathbb F_p$ it gives a point **together with a** (kind of) **symmetry**. (He represents this last object as a point and loop-edge on the point.)

Could anyone explain to me in an simple manner (as intuitive as possible) the differences Toen is trying to explain?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you type the text here what the difference is you want to know ?

Comment: @Dietrich Burde The sile tries to show how Grothendiek new approach (Topos and so on) introduces a new idea of point. The slide shows a contrast between a simple point in C and a point as part of an orbit of itself or something of that kind, which is saif to be a point in F3

Comment: In other words, I would like to read a good explanation about the difference between the two illustrations on that slide.

Comment: @Pece Thanks for the editing. NOw it seems much better. Hopefully it helps to get an answer.

Comment: No answers? :((

Comment: You should read, or at least browse, Eisenbud and Harris's book *The Geometry of Schemes*. They wrote the whole book to answer your question.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez. Thanks for the reference. I will have a look at the book. Anyway, I guess there is a first not too technical answer you could give, right? I would be pleased to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

Toën refers to the fact that considering $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$ or $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ just as topological spaces is in some cases misleading; one should look at the étale toposes (or similar gadgets) of these two "one-point" schemes. For these toposes, there is a sensible definition of "fundamental group", yielding the "étale fundamental group of a scheme". For $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$, this is just the trivial one-element group. But for $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p)$, it's $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, the "profinite completion" of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$. So, up to completion, $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ has the same fundamental group as the circle. The visualization of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ provided by Toën reflects that fact.