# Grothendiek and singular points

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, math-history, visualization

My question relates to the following thread I opened some weeks ago:

[A question regarding Grothendieck , topos and (adelic??) points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384170/a-question-regarding-grothendieck-topos-and-adelic-points)

Specifically, consider this paragraph:

At 1:14:30 and after,

Toen presents the new objects emerging from topos theory in algebraic geometry. He takes the following example: one wants to solve the algebraic equation
X=0
He says that in a classical framework, it just gives us the solution 0, so it's a point. Not that interesting. But with the topos point of view, it gives different solutions depending on where we solve the equation: over C it gives a point (as before), but over a finite field Fp it gives a point together with a (kind of) symmetry. (He represents this last object as a point and loop-edge on the point.)

I would like to know whether the second meaning (that of the topos perspective) relates to the idea of singular point, and, if so, in whch way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say that it has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez. Could you then provide an answer to my question at the end of the thread I linked?

Comment: I don't know anything about toposes (or indeed topoi) but I know this: both nonsingular and singular points are perfectly well-established objects in classical algebraic geometry. Since topos theory is supposed to be generalising (or whatever) the classical point of view, the "topos perspective" on points cannot be any more related to singular points than nonsingular points, or vice versa.TL,DR: what @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez said.